# Oh, no! My text is flickering?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, text, flicker

Basically, I'm trying to create an application that features a bunch of colored rectangles with text written on them that you can click, making it doing stuff. It runs pretty well, except for the fact that the text on each of the buttons (Created using DrawText()) is constantly flickering. Is there anything I can do to potentially fix this problem?

Comment: Sure there is. What it is though would require knowledge of how you have implemented your app.

Comment: Can you give us a chopped down example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: So, basically, in the main loop of the program, I'm calling the draw procedure of the application object. There are a certain number of RECT objects used by the application class, which are all drawn as white blocks using "FillRectangle" in the draw procedure, which are also used as the rectangles for the DrawText calls, also in the draw procedure.

Comment: @Randolph Levant: I think they meant *post some code* in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment above, you describe calling the draw procedure of your application object form your main message loop. This is almost certainly the source of your problem. Not only will it lead to flickering, it sounds like you are running your application at 100% CPU utilization which is not good.

What you should do is handle the `WM_PAINT` message and only paint in response to that message. That is how Windows GUI apps are meant to work. I recommend you read up in any introductory Windows GUI book. The canonical such book is Petzold's Programming Windows.

Comment: Also, to prevent *further* flickering, he should implement the technique of double buffering when painting (protip: it should be disabled when running in a Terminal Server/RDP session).

Comment: @Matteo Actually I disagree. Flicker free apps can be achieved without double buffering. Doing so is to be preferred because double buffering often blocks certain parts of the theme API, for example pulsing buttons.

Comment: @Matteo, if this advice is followed then double buffering would likely be redundant unless the button text is changing rapidly.

Comment: @David: interesting, have you got some article where I can read something about these other techniques?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: On the newer versions of Windows, DWM should be providing that for you (buffering everything between `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`, that is).